# Error: Failed to find '@ionic/angular/css/display.css'

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, angular8, ionic5

I am migrating my ionic project from version 4 to version 5. For that, I have initially installed latest version of ionic 4 with this command

```
npm install @ionic/angular@^4.0.0
```

But now it is giving me this error

```
ERROR in ./src/global.scss (./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/plugins/raw-css-loader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??embedded!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--15-3!./src/global.scss)
[ng] Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):
[ng] Error: Failed to find '@ionic/angular/css/display.css'
[ng]   in [
[ng]     D:\client\app\src
[ng]   ]
[ng]     at resolveModule.catch.catch (D:\client\app\node_modules\postcss-import\lib\resolve-id.js:35:13)
```

Here is my global.scss

```
/*
 * App Global CSS
 * ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Put style rules here that you want to apply globally. These styles are for
 * the entire app and not just one component. Additionally, this file can be
 * used as an entry point to import other CSS/Sass files to be included in the
 * output CSS.
 * For more information on global stylesheets, visit the documentation:
 * https://ionicframework.com/docs/layout/global-stylesheets
 */

/* Core CSS required for Ionic components to work properly */
@import "~@ionic/angular/css/core.css";

/* Basic CSS for apps built with Ionic */
@import "~@ionic/angular/css/normalize.css";
@import "~@ionic/angular/css/structure.css";
@import "~@ionic/angular/css/typography.css";
@import '~@ionic/angular/css/display.css';

/* Optional CSS utils that can be commented out */
@import "~@ionic/angular/css/padding.css";
@import "~@ionic/angular/css/float-elements.css";
@import "~@ionic/angular/css/text-alignment.css";
@import "~@ionic/angular/css/text-transformation.css";
@import "~@ionic/angular/css/flex-utils.css";

@import '~firebaseui/dist/firebaseui.css';


.address-modal{

    .modal-wrapper {
    position: absolute;  
    bottom: 0;  
    height: 80%;

  }
}
```

I can't understand what is going wrong.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

In later versions of Angular, the need to prefix CSS imports from node_modules with a tilde (~) is unnecessary and will cause this error. Remove the tilde and this will work as expected (this is from 4 years ago but still an issue in freshly generated Ionic projects in an NX workspace)